# Template the value of a member variable

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following two classes:

```
Struct Gray
{
const int data_size = 32*32;
int width;
int height;
uint8_t data[data_size ]
}

Struct color
{
const int data_size = 32*32*3;
int width;
int height;
uint8_t data[data_size ]
}
```

I want to combine this 2 classes into one template class.

How can I write such a template class that takes as template parameter the value of data_size, something like `template<int data_size> struct` ? Do we actually use template for such purposes in c++? I know that template are use to tricky variable type but never saw a use case for variable value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* write something of the form

```
template<int size>
struct Foo
{
    // ToDo - other members here
    uint8_t data[size];
};

typedef Foo<32*32> Gray;
typedef Foo<32*32*3> color;
```

**But** note then than `Gray` and `color` are completely different types. As such this pattern is not used that often. One extension would be to use a non-template base class for `Foo` for perhaps the `height` and `width` members. But unless you really do need compile-time features that templates offer, and don't want to use `constexpr` which is another alternative, regular run-time polymorphism is probably the best fit for most purposes.

Comment: It is used often in linear algebra (Eigen, Blaze, MLT, Armadillo...).

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: Indeed it is - because you *want* different sized elements to be unrelated, insofar that say an `int` and a `double` are unrelated.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's one use of templates:

```
template<int size>
struct color
{
    int width;
    int height;
    uint8_t data[size];
};
```

Templates arguments can be a class, but they can also be some simple values like ints.